# jQuery: Scroll position 0 if 100 percent is reached

Tags: jquery, scroll, infinite-scroll

I would need something like an endless scroll function, based on this logic:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var fullHeight = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (fullHeight = 100% ) {
    $("html").scrollTop(0);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

Unfortunately, jQuery doesn't work with such percent values. And I am also not sure if the scroll behavior could be weird this way. Does anyone have an idea how to let this work well?

Comment: https://codepen.io/zz_coder/pen/MWVvPmP

Comment: @Mr.ZZ Thank you! Is there also a way to avoid the scrolling to top movement after reaching 100 percent but still get the zero position again?